# GWT Editor frame work

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

Its normal when i use a DoubleBox in a Editor to edit a double property (RequestFactoryEditorDriver)
if i clear the value of the box i get a null pointer exception?

If so how can i validate a DoubleBox with the JSR 303 Validation?

My code looks something like this:

```
 @DecimalMin(value="0.0", message="decimalMin:0.0", groups = {ImpuestoGroup.class,    ImpuestoIepsGroup.class})
  public double getTasaImpuesto();

 <g:DoubleBox ui:field="tasaImpuesto"></g:DoubleBox>
 @UiField DoubleBox tasaImpuesto;
```

When i call the driver.flush() need to check the constraints i have this results:

if i put a value diferent than number i get the on the List the bad value
if i put a lower than 0.0 value i can set the constraints to the EditorDriver with driver.setConstraintViolations(constraints);

When i leave blank the field i expect a List with a bad value or the constraint but not a null pointer exception.

The line i get my atention is this one:

```
 Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'value_0' of null
at Unknown.$doubleValue(http://localhost:9876/proj/C6E66C9FC3DCB1FC08DFFFC07FE049E0.cache.js@21:38447)
```

Seems that DoubleBox cannot handle the null value.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/IiPJhHcDajU/tSQEZlBuq5kJ), copied here for convenience:

`DoubleBox` uses `DoubleParser`. `DoubleParser` returns `null` if the value is the empty string, and otherwise uses a `NumberFormat`, and throws a `ParserException` if it cannot parse. Your edited object's property is of type `double`, not `java.lang.Double`, so when the field is empty, `getValue()` returns `null`, and the Editor framework tries to unbox the `null` to put it into your `double` property, hence the `NullPointerException`. With any illegal value, `DoubleParser` throws; in that case, the `ValueBoxEditor` returns the last known value, which explains why it doesn't throw in that case.

Request for enhancement: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7783